# Get CPU model name, vendor id, no of physical processors in Windows C

Tags: c, windows, cpu

I saw [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) topic but I doesnt give all the information I need. Is there any PORTABLE way (all Windows's portable only) to get cpu model name, vendor id and no of physical processors?

Comment: Have you looked at the WMI API?

Answer (score 3):

The link you provide is for the mobile versions of Windows, so if by portable you mean the desktop versions as well then [GetSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx/css) is available (as stated) for all versions from Window 2000 and up.

If you need older versions than that then you should give some limits.